# Expected expression error in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am having issues with this block of code:

```
private static func replaceAnimationMethods() {
        //replace actionForLayer...
        method_exchangeImplementations(
            class_getInstanceMethod(self, #selector(UIView.actionForLayer(_:forKey:))),
            class_getInstanceMethod(self, #selector(UIView.EA_actionForLayer(_:forKey:))))

        //replace animateWithDuration...
        method_exchangeImplementations(
            class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(UIView.animateWithDuration(_:animations:))),
            class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(UIView.EA_animateWithDuration(_:animations:))))
        method_exchangeImplementations(
            class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(UIView.animateWithDuration(_:animations:completion:))),
            class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(UIView.EA_animateWithDuration(_:animations:completion:))))
        method_exchangeImplementations(
            class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(UIView.animateWithDuration(_:delay:options:animations:completion:))),
            class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(UIView.EA_animateWithDuration(_:delay:options:animations:completion:))))
        method_exchangeImplementations(
            class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(UIView.animateWithDuration(_:delay:usingSpringWithDamping:initialSpringVelocity:options:animations:completion:))),
            class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(UIView.EA_animateWithDuration(_:delay:usingSpringWithDamping:initialSpringVelocity:options:animations:completion:))))

    }
```

I am trying to migrate to Swift 3.0.

For:

```
class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(UIView.animate(withDuration:animations:)(_:animations:))),
```

I am getting the error `Expected expression in list of expressions`.

For:

```
class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(UIView.animate(withDuration:animations:completion:)(_:animations:completion:))),
```

I am getting the error `Expected ',' separator`

Stuck for ideas how to fix this. Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like below syntaxes.

```
class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(UIView.animate(withDuration:animations:)))
class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(UIView.animate(withDuration:animations:completion:)))
```